# Trying to find occurrences of ID that meets sequential conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, dplyr, logical-operators

I'm trying to return a logical vector based on whether a person meets one set of conditions and ALSO meets another set of conditions later on. I'm using a data frame that looks like so:

```
Person.Id     Year       Term

250             1         3
250             1         1
250             2         3  
300             1         3           
511             2         1
300             1         5
700             2         3
```

What I want to return is a logical vector that indicates true/false if person ID 250  has year 1 and term 3, AND later has year 2 term 3. So a person that only has year 1 term 3 or year 1 term 5 will return false. Solutions in dplyr preferred! I feel like this is simple and I'm just missing something. I initially tried this code but all it returned was a blank df:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
        group_by(Person.Id) %>%
        filter((year==1 & term==3) & (year==2 & term==3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
require(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Person.Id) %>% 
  mutate(count=sum((year==1 & term==3) | (year==2 & term==3))) %>% 
  mutate(count2=if_else(count==2,T,F))

# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   Person.Id [4]
  Person.Id  year  term count count2
      <int> <int> <int> <int> <lgl> 
1       250     1     3     2 TRUE  
2       250     1     1     2 TRUE  
3       250     2     3     2 TRUE  
4       300     1     3     1 FALSE 
5       511     2     1     0 FALSE 
6       300     1     5     1 FALSE 
7       700     2     3     1 FALSE
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help:

```
#Data
Data <- structure(list(Person.Id = c(250L, 250L, 250L, 300L, 511L, 300L, 
700L), Year = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Term = c(3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
#Flags
cond1 <- Data$Year==1 & Data$Term==3
cond2 <- Data$Year==2 & Data$Term==3
#Replace
Data$Flag1 <- 0
Data$Flag1[cond1]<-1
Data$Flag2 <- 0
Data$Flag2[cond2]<-1
#Filter 
Data %>% group_by(Person.Id) %>% filter(Flag1==1 | Flag2==1)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   Person.Id [3]
  Person.Id  Year  Term Flag1 Flag2
      <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1       250     1     3     1     0
2       250     2     3     0     1
3       300     1     3     1     0
4       700     2     3     0     1
```